# How do you know which hooks in WordPress receive a _POST request?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

How do you know a `_POST` request was sent to a hook? Do you just check `if isset($_POST)` within the function being fired in the hook and go from there?

For example this hook from WooCommerce that allows you to update order meta:
`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`
[Link](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-checkout.html#source-view.398)

I wrote a function that needed to process some data from the order being placed using this hook, and examples used the `_POST` global variable to get the form data submitted. How do you know the `_POST` variable is available? I only know its available in this hook now because of examples.

My question is not just limited to this WooCommerce hook, it is for ALL hooks. How do you actually know if a `_POST` is available/sent to the hook?

Example function:

```php
function tw_save_billing_phone_number($order_id) {
    
    if ( !isset($_POST['billing_phone']) || empty($_POST['billing_phone']) ) return;

    $billing_phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_phone']);

    // update the billing phone number for the order
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order->set_billing_phone($billing_phone);
    $order->save();

    // update the billing phone number for the user
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', $billing_phone);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'tw_save_billing_phone_number');
```

The only thing I can think of to check if a hook receives a `_POST` is to check it with `isset()` then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

the first check is performed using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to ensure that the request method is POST. If it is not a POST request, the function returns early.

```
function tw_save_billing_phone_number($order_id) {
    // Check if a POST request was sent
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the billing_phone field is available in the POST data
    if (!isset($_POST['billing_phone']) || empty($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
        return;
    }

    $billing_phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_phone']);

    // Update the billing phone number for the order
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order->set_billing_phone($billing_phone);
    $order->save();

    // Update the billing phone number for the user
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    if ($user_id) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', $billing_phone);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'tw_save_billing_phone_number');
```